# Given independent random variables $X,Y$, and $M=\min(X,Y)$, what is $E(XM\mid Y=M)$?

Tags: expected-value, independence, conditional-expectation, exponential-distribution

Given independent random variables $X,Y$, and $M=\min(X,Y)$, what is $E(XM\mid Y=M)$ ?

The specific case I'm working on is assuming $X$ and $Y$ are exponential random variables with mean $\theta_X$ and $\theta_Y$. I'm curious about what is  the general formula for any random variable?

Comment: I think this might be easier to understand if it was asking for $E[XY \mid X\ge Y]$.  If $X$ and $Y$ were iid with continuous distributions then this would be $(E[X])^2$

Answer (score 0):

Observe that

$$E\left[X\min(X,Y)\mid Y=\min(X,Y)\right]=E\left[XY\mid X\ge Y\right] $$

As long as $P(X\ge Y)>0$, the above conditional expectation is defined as

$$E\left[XY\mid X\ge Y\right]=\frac{E\left[XYI(X\ge Y)\right]}{P(X\ge Y)}\,,$$

where $I(\cdot)$ is an indicator variable.

One can use the law of total expectation to find these quantities.

For example, if $f_X$ is the pdf of $X$,

\begin{align}
E\left[XY I(X\ge Y)\right]&=E\,E\left[XY I(X\ge Y)\mid Y\right]
\\&=E\left[YE\left[XI(X\ge Y)\mid Y\right]\right]
\\&=E\left[Y\int_Y^\infty xf_X(x)\,dx\right]
\end{align}

If $X$ and $Y$ are exponential, then this reduces to

\begin{align}
E\left[XY I(X\ge Y)\right]&=E\left[Y \int_Y^\infty \frac{x}{\theta_X}e^{-x/\theta_X}\,dx\right]
\\&=E\left[Y e^{-Y/\theta_X}(\theta_X+Y)\right]
\\&=\theta_XE\left[Ye^{-Y/\theta_X}\right]+E\left[Y^2e^{-Y/\theta_X}\right]
\end{align}

The rest is straightforward using the pdf of $Y$.

Similarly, I can say

$$P(X\ge Y)=E\left[I(X\ge Y)\right]=E\,E\left[I(X\ge Y)\mid Y\right]=E\,P(X\ge Y\mid Y)$$

and simplify as before.